# Spring Boot Query Selection With Case Sensitive

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have to do in Spring Boot an LoginController which verifies if a username and password exists in database or not. For verification I made my repository, UserRepository which extends CrudRepository.

When I send the username and password to repository, they are sent okay, but when I do the query it doesn't take into account the case sensitivity of my parameters.

For example: in USER table I have username = "Test" and password = "test"
             If I make an request with username = "test" and password = "Test" it seems like I have this username and password in the table, but I haven't.

Bellow I put a peace of code with my query and I would be very grateful if you could help me with this problem.

Thank you for your time.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{

User findByUsername(String username);

User findByEmail(String email);

@Query(value = "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username = :username AND password = :password", nativeQuery = true)
Long findUserIdByUsernameAndPassword(@Param("username") String username, @Param("password") String password);
```

}

Comment: I believe the default for these is supposed to be case-sensitive, because `IgnoreCase` is a special keyword for [Spring Data JPA queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation). `findByEmail` should be case-sensitive, but `findByEmailIgnoreCase` would not be case-sensitive. What have you tried to check the values being passed into the function and the values on the DB are not the same casing?

Comment: Yes, I verified. After I make the request in postman I print the username and password and they are okay.
And from DB.... I've made a query which returns the username for one specifically user_id and returns well.

Comment: You may want to look at [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15254) to a similar question. Depending on how the MySQL db is created, strings may be case-insensitive by default apparently.

Comment: And I tried to create the method without using query annotation, just declaration of the method, but I can't select just user_id like I do right now. I have to change from "Long findByUsernameAndPassword" to "User findByUsernameAndPassword"

Comment: I believe [Wrokar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755459/spring-boot-query-selection-with-case-sensitive#comment90470823_51755459) is correct, and this is a database issue, not a Spring or JPA issue.

Comment: @Wrokar, thank you very much. Now the login it works properly.

Comment: This issue has to be down at the database level, not at the Spring level.  And MySQL is known to be problematic - it performs case insensitive comparisons when you might expect case sensitivity.  [This page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) has some information that may be useful to you.

Comment: (And as usual, other people type faster than I do).

Comment: Thank you ^_^^_^